# Why BigOmega(n)?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I am reading "Introduction to Algorithms" by T. H. Cormen et al.
There is the following problem in this book.

Exercises 6.2-6:
Show that the worst-case running time of MAX-HEAPIFY on a heap of size n is BigOmega(n).

Why BigOmega(n) instead of BigTheta(n)?

I think BigTheta(n) is natural when we consider the worst-case or the best-case running time of an algorithm.

Comment: BigTheta(n) implies BigOmega(n), correct? Because the book want to ask you that. We can't read book writers' mind.

Comment: I think BIgTheta(n) is natural when We consider the worst-case or the best-case running time of an algorithm.

Comment: [This paper](http://www.phil.uu.nl/datastructuren/10-11/knuth_big_omicron.pdf) from D. Knuth will help you understand why he introduced the omega-based notation.